# PieSeries shows only thin line instead of a full slice color when one value is 100% of total value

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am experiencing a strange behaviour of RadPieChart  and PieSeries.

PieSeries is showing only a thin line when one value represents 100% of total.

EDIT: here is the link for Playground demo, if you want to try it out on your device - https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=ZxmuR5&v=2

or you can use this link of my github project if you want to test it on your device: https://github.com/VukMNE/PieSeriesMalfunction

If my description is not clear, bellow are images to illustrate the problem I am facing. First image shows regular behavior of PieSeries, and the second one shows the problematic behavior.

Bellow is the example of a normal pie chart that is working correctly in my app. There are two slices, and both of them are filled with color.

[image: Normal pie chart]

But if one value is the equal to the total amount, instead of showing a one slice filled with color, it is only showing a thin line.

[image]

The code for both charts is identical. These charts are dynamic, and they display different data based on the parameters from the user. However, bellow is the code for both charts.

```
<RadPieChart *ngIf="!noDataFound" tkExampleTitle tkToggleNavButton minHeight="200" allowAnimation="true" row="0">
        <PieSeries tkPieSeries
            seriesName="collectPie"
            selectionMode="None"
            expandRadius="0.4"
            outerRadiusFactor="0.7"
            valueProperty="amountCollected"
            legendLabel="nameForLabel"
            showLabels="true"
            showPercentage="false"
            [items]="pieSourceCollected">
            <PointLabelStyle tkPieLabelStyle margin="15" textFormat="%.2f €"></PointLabelStyle>
        </PieSeries>
        <Palette tkPiePalette seriesName="collectPie">
            <PaletteEntry tkPiePaletteEntry fillColor="#1B998B" strokeColor="#1B998B"></PaletteEntry>
            <PaletteEntry tkPiePaletteEntry fillColor="#97C8EB" strokeColor="#97C8EB"></PaletteEntry>
            <PaletteEntry tkPiePaletteEntry fillColor="#001F54" strokeColor="#001F54"></PaletteEntry>
            <PaletteEntry tkPiePaletteEntry fillColor="#2B193D" strokeColor="#2B193D"></PaletteEntry>
            <PaletteEntry tkPiePaletteEntry fillColor="#484D6D" strokeColor="#484D6D"></PaletteEntry>
            <PaletteEntry tkPiePaletteEntry fillColor="#2C365E" strokeColor="#2C365E"></PaletteEntry>
        </Palette>
        <RadLegendView tkPieLegend position="Top" width="100%"></RadLegendView>
      </RadPieChart>
```

Code for the second chart:

```
<RadPieChart *ngIf="!noDataFound" tkExampleTitle tkToggleNavButton minHeight="200" allowAnimation="true" row="0">
        <PieSeries tkPieSeries
            seriesName="collectPie"
            selectionMode="None"
            expandRadius="0.4"
            outerRadiusFactor="0.7"
            valueProperty="amountSpent"
            legendLabel="nameForLabel"
            showLabels="true"
            showPercentage="false"
            [items]="pieSourceSpent">
            <PointLabelStyle tkPieLabelStyle margin="15" textFormat="%.2f €"></PointLabelStyle>
        </PieSeries>
        <Palette tkPiePalette seriesName="collectPie">
            <PaletteEntry tkPiePaletteEntry fillColor="#1B998B" strokeColor="#1B998B"></PaletteEntry>
            <PaletteEntry tkPiePaletteEntry fillColor="#97C8EB" strokeColor="#97C8EB"></PaletteEntry>
            <PaletteEntry tkPiePaletteEntry fillColor="#001F54" strokeColor="#001F54"></PaletteEntry>
            <PaletteEntry tkPiePaletteEntry fillColor="#2B193D" strokeColor="#2B193D"></PaletteEntry>
            <PaletteEntry tkPiePaletteEntry fillColor="#484D6D" strokeColor="#484D6D"></PaletteEntry>
            <PaletteEntry tkPiePaletteEntry fillColor="#2C365E" strokeColor="#2C365E"></PaletteEntry>
        </Palette>    
        <RadLegendView tkPieLegend position="Top" width="100%"></RadLegendView>
      </RadPieChart>
```

I have even tried filtering the datasource for the chart, by removing the values that are equal to zero, but the bug is still there. It should show a full pie, instead of this thin line, shouldn't it?

[image]

Comment: Can you share a Playground sample, that would help to debug the issue with same data as your are using.

Comment: Thank you for your interest. I will publish the sample tomorrow!

Comment: @Manoj I was not able to publish this app to playground because of the nativescript-ui-chart plugin. However, if it s helpful, here is the link to my github project: https://github.com/VukMNE/PieSeriesMalfunction

Comment: Because of nativescript-ui-chart plugin? All NativeScript UI plugins are supported in Playground.

Comment: @Manoj I have reported this issue on github, and NativeScript developers have confirmed that this is a bug, here is the link for github issue: https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-ui-feedback/issues/1318

Comment: @Manoj And here is the link for playground sample that you have requested: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=ZxmuR5&v=2